reversed positioning of object
I have a problem with moving my object. When I drag the body of this man, its mesh goes in opposite way of how I drag the origin. First picture is before, second is after i dragged.



Your screenshots are a bit confusing. First of all they are from different viewpoints, that makes it harder to understand in which way the movement is incorrect. And from what it looks like in the second screenshot, the mesh is mostly going upwards compared to the first, but the first shows a negative Z movement, the second a positive Z movement so it looks correct to me. However the values show you are moving it ≈ 2.9 centimeters down and ≈ 5.7 centimeters up... which makes me think this is the classical unapplied scale problem... maybe negative scale (rotated axes as well?).
